# How can I get elements from the "A" matrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I would like to know if there is any way (I'm sure it is) to get the elements of the
additive relationship matrix A in R.
I already have the pedigree and I was succesfull on getting the A matrix by to different ways:

1. by using the function makeA from the pedigree package:

```r
library(pedigree)
makeA(pedigree_renum, which = pedigree_renum$ID=="1-2372") #for all the animals
#> [1] TRUE
```

but I can not get the elements from the matrix

2. by using the function getA from the peigreemm package. In this case I get the 2372*2372 A matrix:

```r
class(pedigree_general)
#> [1] "pedigree"
attr(,"package")
#> [1] "pedigreemm"
matrizA<-getA(pedigree_general)
class(matrizA)
#> [1] "dsCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
#> [1] "Matrix"
```

But I can't find out how to save certain elements from the matrix such as the upper diagonal elements.

Hope some of you can help me figure this out!
Different approaches to obtain the same result are welcome :)

Greetings from Buenos Aires.

Answer (score 0):

From Pedigree's documentation on [`makeA`](https://rdrr.io/cran/pedigree/man/makeA.html):

> Makes the A matrix for a part of a pedigree and stores it in a file called **A.txt**

What you have missed, if I'm not mistaken, is that the matrix you are searching for should be loaded from the file `A.txt`, which is the output file of the command. Example:

```
id <- 1:6
dam <- c(0,0,1,1,4,4)
sire <- c(0,0,2,2,3,5)
ped <- data.frame(id,dam,sire)
makeA(ped,which = c(rep(FALSE,4),rep(TRUE,2)))
A <- read.table("A.txt")
```

After printing A, here is the matrix:

[image]

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I will try it and let you know if that works. Thanks!!

Comment: You are absolutely right, so by reading this I realized that my mistake is the logical vector that indicated which animals I request the A matrix for: which = pedigree_renum$ID=="1-2372" how can I ask R to consider all the animals?

Comment: look at this: after running the code it shows  > id <- 1:6
> dam <- c(0,0,1,1,4,4)
> sire <- c(0,0,2,2,3,5)
> ped <- data.frame(id,dam,sire)
> A<-makeA(ped,which = c(rep(FALSE,4),rep(TRUE,2)))
> print(A)
[1] TRUE    I don't know whats wrong. I can't get the matrix you showed, and that is exactly what I need for my 2372 animals!

Comment: You should not be assigning the return of `makeA` to the variable `A`. It is instead obtained from the file `A.txt`, so the `A <- read.table("A.txt")` (where `A.txt` was created by `makeA`) is what makes the matrix get read into `R`. To be clearer, `makeA` does not return the matrix, it saves it in the file A.txt instead so it needs to be read after the `makeA` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood how makeA works and I now I have my A matrix!